# I am facing data.ember issue in my google colab how to resolve it?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I am trying to train a model but I am getting this error. I have installed data library but this error is not solving. anyone can guide me how to get rid of it. Thanks
[image]

Comment: that's a very suspiciously named library. What's the exact package on PyPI? How did you install it? Also, don't use images of code, please code paste code and errors in formatted code blocks.

Comment: @RobinDeSchepper here is the link of Colab

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IPTUQR3DDww6E43NNcIqgHJ4Y6Eg5pMg/view?usp=sharing